# Почему не ставится запятая между двумя основами?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп, и, основа

Но лишь только после трагедии давали фарс(,) и Мольер, переодевшись, превращался из Цезаря в Сганареля, дело менялось в ту же минуту: публика начинала хохотать, публика аплодировала, происходили овации, на следующие спектакли горожане несли деньги.

Тут же две основы – *давали, Мольер превращался.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Но лишь только после трагедии давали фарс **и** Мольер, переодевшись, превращался из Цезаря в Сганареля, дело менялось в ту же минуту...*

Это сложноподчинённое предложение с союзом [***лишь только***](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_397).
Можно поменять порядок предложений:
*Но дело менялось в ту же минуту, **лишь только** после трагедии давали фарс **и** Мольер, переодевшись, превращался из Цезаря в Сганареля.*
Запятая перед союзом ***и*** не ставится по следующему правилу.

> **3.** Между однородными придаточными частями сложноподчиненного предложения, связанными неповторяющимися союзами (соединительными или разделительными) запятая не ставится.

[**Знаки препинания в сложноподчиненном предложении с несколькими придаточными** (справочник Розенталя)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=139)

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо!

Comment: Здравствуйте, Andew! Спасибо за вопрос и оценку!

Answer (score 0):

Мне на другом форуме ответили:
У частей этого сложного предложения имеется общий член - обстоятельство "после трагедии".
Если в сложносочиненном предложении имеются общие второстепенные члены, относящиеся в равной степени к каждому простому предложению, знак препинания не  ставится перед союзом. Например:

"К концу дня дождь перестал _ и ветер начал заметно стихать".

"Вокруг нас гулко жужжали шмели и пчёлы_ или трещали кузнечики".
Ссылка на вопрос: https://otvet.mail.ru/question/235244335

Comment: Да, я тоже сначала подумал об общем второстепенном члене и даже привёл это правило. Это сюда бы подошло, если бы не более сложная структура. ***После трагедии** давали фарс и Мольер превращался...* Хотя и в этом случае запятая возможна, если "после трагедии" не рассматривать как общее.

Comment: В Грамматике Кустовой (2013 год)  "Синтаксис соврем. русского языка" ЛИШЬ ТОЛЬКО  – это союз-частица, рассматривается в теме СПП. Также в издании 2005 года  (стр. 204)  считается союзом  в СПП https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf

Comment: На mail.ru ответ уже удалили.